# Multilingual Entities Wit.AI (import app)

Tags: nlp, wit.ai

## ImportApp #Multilingual

I want to make multilingual chatbot.Currently made a chatbot using the English language with 30+ entities.
Query: How you doing
Entity: E1

Want to check results for the Spanish language.So I exported app and imported to a new app with language equals to Spanish.

Query : comment vas-tu
(Using google translate "how you doing")

No entity detected by wit.

Please let me know how to make multilingual chatbot using wit.ai